# Draw hyperplane in R?

Tags: r, plot

How does one go about drawing an hyperplane (given the equation) in 3D in R ?
(i.e. 3d equivalent to "abline")

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want the packages *[scatterplot3d](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/scatterplot3d/index.html)* or *[HH](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/HH/index.html)* (function `regr2.plot`). See, e.g., this [example](http://rgraphgallery.blogspot.co.at/2013/04/rg-3d-scatter-plots-with-vertical-lines.html) for `scatterplot3d`.

Comment: also see `curve3d()` in the `emdbook` package.

Answer (score 6):

[Lattice supports 3D charts](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lattice/index.html).  See some of the nice examples from [Lattice: Multivariate Data Visualization with R](http://lmdvr.r-forge.r-project.org/figures/figures.html) on [the LearnR blog](http://learnr.wordpress.com/2009/07/20/ggplot2-version-of-figures-in-lattice-multivariate-data-visualization-with-r-part-6/).  For instance, with `wireframe()`:

```
pl <- wireframe(fit.linear + fit.loess.1 + fit.loess.2 +
+     fit.locfit ~ wind * temperature | radiation, grid,
+     outer = TRUE, shade = TRUE, zlab = "")
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot: rcs's reply solves a punctual problem, but on a longer term thanks for the link: the plots there R outstanding...